# CultureInfo.CurrentCulture wrong

Tags: c#, .net

My .Net program gives me a wrong value for `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`. The value is de-de but my system is en-us. This is the obvious test program:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string language = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
    }
```

I follow these instructions when I look at my Windows language settings:

- Click Start, then Control Panel. Click Clock, Language and Region.
- Windows 10: Click Region. ... Click the Administrative tab. ...
- Under the Language for non-Unicode programs section, click "Change system locale and select the desired language".

It shows "English (United Stated)" as expected. My Windows is English too, e.g. the explorer menu.

What can be the reason that the .Net program comes up as German?

Comment: [Imagine if there was documentation around this.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=netcore-3.1#how-a-threads-culture-is-determined)

Comment: That was the documentation I was actually reading but I couldn't find something that would explain the phenomena. It says CurrentCulture is determined by  DefaultThreadCurrentCulture. Both are de-de on an US system. I do not understand.

Comment: Why would you think that "Language for non-Unicode programs" would be the thing that determines your system locale? Your Windows is set to German locale somewhere somehow, and it's not the tooth fairy that's done it.

Comment: Maybe I am confused, but "Language for non-Unicode programs" is set to en-us, hence CurrentCulture is de-de. What other settings could it be that .net is looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found out where .net gets its CurrentCulture Setting from. It's *not* from

- Control Panel -> Click Clock, Language and Region -> ...

but from

- Start -> Settings -> Time & Language -> Region -> Regional format.

Whatever the difference is!